# QTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I've seen some people with the same problem than me, but solution won't work for me.

Here's my code :

I'm writing a program that send an UDP frame every 10 mS. Here's how my program is supposed to work :

I've got a `client class` :

```
//Constructor
clientSupervision::clientSupervision()
{
}

void clientSupervision::sendDataUDP(){
    //Create a frame and send it
...
}

void clientSupervision::sendDataUDPTimer(int timer){
    QTimer *tempsEnvoieTrameSupervision = new QTimer();//Create a timer
    tempsEnvoieTrameSupervision->setInterval(timer);//Set the interval

    //Mise en place des connections
    QObject::connect (tempsEnvoieTrameSupervision,SIGNAL (timeout()),this, SLOT (envoiTrameSupervision())); //Connect the timer to the function
    tempsEnvoieTrameSupervision->start();// Start the timer
}

//Call sendDataUDP
void clientSupervision::envoiTrameSupervision(){
    std::cout << "Envoi de la trame de supervision";
    sendDataUDP();
}
```

Then I use this in my `main` :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    clientSupervision c;
    c.sendDataUDPTimer(10);
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Why can't the timer work ? Does I have to lauch it somewhere else ?

Thanks.

Comment: Create the `QCoreApplication` first and then run your program again.

Comment: @RobbieE Dude thank you ! And let's go for down voters people :(